How to run android profiler on Android TV apps efficiently?
I am working on Android TV app development. Since most of the Android TV devices have limited memory (max 2-3 GB RAM), running android profiler on these devices slow down the device and profiler is not able to capture the actual data or device hangs in between.
Is there any other way to check android app's performance on android TV, i want to measure below KPIs

CPU usage and system traces
Java/Kotlin Method call traces
Janke frames
Method call stacktrace

I have tried running profiler on 2.5 GB RAM device, but as soon as profiler starts, device hangs and not able to capture CPU related traces.

Below would be my recommendations:

If the API level of your TV is high enough (API 29 and above), try building your app as 'profileable' or 'low overhead' via the main toolbar options (should be next to run and debug). This type of build has less overhead while profiling than the debuggable build (see: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#profileable-apps)

Try out the Task-Based Profiler available in the Koala Feature Drop (available in preview right now: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview); the stable version will be available in a few weeks. This new Profiler has less overhead than the previous one, and will also direct you to the preferred/most optimal build type for each task.

You can always manually perform a trace via command line, and then use adb pull to retrieve the trace file from the device onto your host. This removes the overhead any profiling application on your host introduces.


